# Error: __tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error - iOS 10

Tags: ios, xmlhttprequest, nsurlconnection, ios10, xcode8

While sending XML base API Request to ONVIF Camera. It worked fine on ios 9 device, but giving '500 Internal Error' on iOS 10.

XCode 8 Console prints below error messages:

```
2016-09-30 12:39:51.295419 VCPlugin[278:10183] [] nw_socket_get_input_frames recvmsg(fd 12, 1024 bytes): [54] Connection reset by peer
2016-09-30 12:39:51.301221 VCPlugin[278:10228] [] nw_socket_write_close shutdown(12, SHUT_WR): [57] Socket is not connected
2016-09-30 12:39:51.301307 VCPlugin[278:10228] [] nw_endpoint_flow_service_writes [3 10.107.2.153:80 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Write request has 0 frame count, 0 byte count
2016-09-30 12:39:51.301903 VCPlugin[278:10185] [] __tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [89] Operation canceled
2016-09-30 12:41:13.492053 VCPlugin[278:10287] [] __tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [57] Socket is not connected
2016-09-30 12:42:51.278617 VCPlugin[278:10228] [] __tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [22] Invalid argument
```

If user retry and retry three-to-four times, then after get valid xml response from server.

I don't know this iOS 10 behaviour.

this is code i have written for call XML API post request:

```
NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:body];
[urlRequest setValue: @"application/soap+xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[urlRequest setValue: @"application/soap+xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data1, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
        if(error == nil)
        {
             NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data1 encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
              NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);
        }
}];

[dataTask resume];
```

Also read [Apple Form](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48959), but not get solution.

Answer (score 7):

try this code:

I have the same issue, but there is something you can do to,

1) Go in Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme
2) Run Section on the left, select Argument Tab and in Environment Variable put this.

> OS_ACTIVITY_MODE to value : disable.

For more information please find the below screenshot.

[image]

This will get rid of messages in the console.

But I still struggle with the `PLBuildVersion` is implemented in both....

I hope this helps you !

Comment: Thanks Bhadresh, your solution helped to remove message from console. But still facing '500 Internal Error' in XML response.

Comment: but this same code working fine in iOS 9.0 and previous versions. Only in iOS 10 is giving '500 Internal Error'.

Comment: yes request and response both in XML format. thank you

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution to your problem?  I am finding the same thing in my app, but I think its related to the webserver getting overloaded with multiple simultaneous requests.  For me it only started after I started sending multiple requests at once.  I'm looking into asynchronously slowing the requests to see if it still happens.

Comment: Hi all, i have this bug, in browser all ok, in device - error, totally helped - clean+reboot device+clear derived data