# nw_socket_write_close shutdown (15, SHUT_WR): [57] Socket is not connected

Tags: swift3, ios10, background-fetch, xcode8.2

While running my app in the background fetch, after a few fetches i receive the following error. Im using iOS 10.2.1 and Xcode Version 8.2.1
I have enabled background fetch in capabilities. Would anyone be able to tell me why its happening?

[image]

2017-02-02 14:28:09.738682 ********* [446:57355] [] nw_socket_get_input_frames recvmsg(fd 15, 1024 bytes): [57] Socket is not connected

2017-02-02 14:28:09.738979 *********[446:57355] [] nw_socket_write_close shutdown(15, SHUT_WR): [57] Socket is not connected

2017-02-02 14:28:09.739172 *********[446:57355] [] nw_endpoint_flow_service_writes [6.1 216.58.193.74:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Write request has 0 frame count, 0 byte count

2017-02-02 14:28:09.739522 *********[446:64570] [] __tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [89] Operation canceled

Comment: Have you set up a background URLSesisonConfiguration?  https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration

Comment: No I have not. What should I do. Im going to read your link. Thanks

Comment: Have you find the solution?

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39791849/1491675 it's a system message, not a bug in your code. This will help you turn it off in the log.